# Set environment variable for subshell invocation

Tags: zsh

I want to extend the concept to be able to set an environment variable just for the invocation of one subprocess, i.e.

```
VARIABLE=VALUE COMMAND PARAMETERS
```

for instance

```
FOO=6 printenv FOO
```

to the case, where COMMAND is a subshell. As an example to demonstrate this problem, I used

```
 FOO=6 BAR=7 ( printenv FOO; printenv BAR )
```

which resulted in a

```
zsh: parse error near `('
```

Why is it that this does not work, although

```
 export FOO=6
 export BAR=7
 ( printenv FOO; printenv BAR )
```

does work. Of course I could do a

```
# Explicit call of zsh needed:
FOO=6 BAR=7 zsh -c 'printenv FOO; printenv BAR'
```

or a

```
# Two nested subshells, instead of one, and a lot more to type:
 (export FOO=6; export BAR=7; (printenv FOO; printenv BAR))
```

but is there also a simple way using notation with parenthesis for the subshell?

I somehow feel that I'm lacking something fundamental in making subshells using `(....)`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use the export variant within a single subshell. There's no need for a secondary nested subshell.

```sh
$ (export FOO=6; export BAR=7; printenv FOO; printenv BAR);
6
7
```

Comment: Of course: My nested subshell was unnecessary. So I guess there is no way to avoid writing an explicit `export` statement? Could you elaborate a bit, why my original attempt failed with a _parse error_?